# yii2 ActiveRecord query to get a specific relation object

Tags: mysql, activerecord, yii2, relationship

Lets say I have a product. That product can have multiple texts. In my query I only want to get a specific text. I dont want to get all the texts and then make a loop to ckeck. Is that possible? I tried a couple things:

```
$nameArticle = Product::find([
    'id',
    'pld.product_name as productName'
])
    ->from('product p')
    ->joinWith('productLanguageData.language')
    ->where(['p.id' => $value['product']])
    ->andWhere(['pl.iso_language' => 'es']) //query, please give me only spanish text.
    ->one();
```

This returns product with all the languages.

How can i make this query work?

```
public function getLanguage()
{
    return $this->hasOne(ProductLanguage::className(), ['id' => 'language_id'])
        ->from(['pl' => ProductLanguage::tableName()]);
}
```

Comment: There is no  **pl** alias defined i guess.

Comment: pl alias is defined in the model. Updated my question.

Comment: Try this `$language = ProductLanguage::find()->where(["product_id"=>$productId,"iso_language"=>"es"])->one();`